# Android Studio + emulator consume a lot of memory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ram

My configuration: 
Processor: 3.10 GHz RAM: 8 GB 
Windows 7 (64 bit) 
Android Studio 2.2.2
Java 1.8

I try the next solutions, but this is not help me.

File->Settings->Plugins and disable the following things:
CVS Integration, Git Integration, GitHub, Google Cloud Tools for Android Studio, Subversion Integration

In file gradle.properites:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M

In file  studio.exe.vmoptions:
 -server -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

But when I start emulator its take very much RAM , and as result my computer work VERY slow. Here screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the name of your processor?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio,

1. Goto Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager
2. Select the emulator you are using and press Edit (Pencil icon).
3. In the Virtual Device Configuration window, click on Show Advanced Setting.
4. Scroll down to Memory & Storage
5. RAM textfield, enter 512 and select MB in the dropdown box next to it.
6. Finish!
7. Restart your emulator and your problem solved!

Comment: That doesnt work... because less amount of ram causes emulator doesnt even start. more recent emulator describes that minimal amount of RAM is above 1024mb and the recommended ram is about 2048mb :/